# Vue.JS Generate manifest.json with .env variables

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, progressive-web-apps

I'm using Vue.JS 2, and I'm looking for something to generate the `manifest.json` for PWA with webpack and environment variables. E.g I'll put the primary color in my `.env`, and then I can set the `"theme_color": VUE_APP_THEME_COLOR` in my `manifest.json`.

I tried to do this way in the `vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.plugin("pwa").tap((args) => {
      args[0].theme_color = VUE_APP_THEME_COLOR;
      return args;
    });
```

But it has no effect to the manifest. It doesn't override the manifest in the `public/` folder.

Comment: I'm not properly sure, but I think the pwa plugin will only create a manifest.json file in the built files folder if no manifest.json file is already present in the public folder... I'll check for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure [`pwa.themeColor`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pwa) as follows:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  pwa: {
    themeColor: process.env.VUE_APP_THEME_COLOR,
  }
}
```

Also, since you're using `public/manifest.json`, which has precedence over the `pwa` configuration, make sure to remove `theme_color` from that file:

```json
// public/manifest.json
{
  "theme_color": #eee, // ❌REMOVE THIS
}
```

[GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue-pwa-themecolor-demo/blob/master/dist/manifest.json#L4)

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, I tried your way but it's ignored. It will not override the themecolor in the default manifest.json in the public folder

Comment: When I run `npm run serve` it take data from manifest.json in public folder. The themeColor that I specify in the vue.config.js is ignored I don't know why

Comment: @John Make sure to remove `theme_color` from `public/manifest.json`, which has precedence over `pwa` config. See updated answer and demo.

Comment: Yes I already removed `theme_color` from `public/manifest.json` and when I run my application the `theme_color` property is empty, it doesn't take the `themeColor` in my `vue.config.js`. For the moment I set `themeColor: "#000000"` but it still empty when my application is running

Comment: Can you fork the GitHub demo I linked to reproduce the problem? There seems to be a unique problem in your case that isn't obvious from your question.

Comment: Hmmm yes I see, your solution is working when I create a new project, but in my project it doesn't work :/. In my test project, the manifest.json isn't create in public folder. So I tried to remove my manifest.json to and build my project but it doesn't generate the manifest.json when I build. I miss something. I can't share my project :( I'll try to find the problem thank you

Comment: Ok I found the problem, my `"@vue/cli-plugin-pwa"` was in version 3, I updated to the version 4.5 and now it works. Thanks for the help

Comment: I have a problem to include assets for pwa icon I created a post for that : https://stackoverflow.com/q/64662819/2519631