# VueJS webpack PWA assets icons manifest.json

Tags: vue.js, webpack, progressive-web-apps

I configured my PWA `manifest.json` in `vue.config.js`, shown below. How can I configure the PWA icons to refer to the images inside the `assets/` folder?

```js
module.exports = {
    pwa: {
        manifestOptions: {
          name: process.env.VUE_APP_APP_NAME,
          short_name: process.env.VUE_APP_SHORT_NAME,
          start_url: process.env.VUE_APP_START_URL,
          display: 'standalone',
          theme_color: process.env.VUE_APP_PRIMARY_COLOR,
          background_color: process.env.VUE_APP_BACKGROUND_COLOR,
          icons: [
            {
              src: `src/assets/${process.env.VUE_APP_COMPANY}/logo-192x192.png`,
              sizes: "192x192",
              type: "image/png"
            },
            {
              src: `src/assets/${process.env.VUE_APP_COMPANY}/logo-512x512.png`,
              sizes: "512x512",
              type: "image/png"
            }
          ]
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my app, I get this error :

```
http://localhost:8080/src/assets/company/logo-512x512.png (Download error or resource isn't a valid image)
```

I don't understand why `/src` is set in the URL.

Comment: /src is set in the url because you've set it in the `src` definition.

Comment: @geoidesic but how can I access to my assets file in src folder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [static assets from the `public` directory](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder) (e.g., `public/img/company/logo-192x192.png` and `public/img/company/logo-512x512.png`), which are copied as-is to the build output. Then your `vue.config.js` would reference them like this:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  pwa: {
    manifestOptions: {
      icons: [
        {
          src: `/img/${process.env.VUE_APP_COMPANY}/logo-192x192.png`,
          sizes: "192x192",
          type: "image/png"
        },
        {
          src: `/img/${process.env.VUE_APP_COMPANY}/logo-512x512.png`,
          sizes: "512x512",
          type: "image/png"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know it works if I use images in the public directory but there is no way to use image from assets directory for PWA icons ? Currently it works for the favicon app with :    `config.plugin("html").tap((args) => { args[0].favicon = 'src/assets/${process.env.VUE_APP_COMPANY}/favicon.ico';`... that is why I'm searching to do the same for PWA icons. But if it's impossible I will place my PWA files in the public directory

Comment: It's not impossible. It could be done separately from the `pwa` config by configuring Webpack to process (optimize) the icons from `assets`, and to copy output to `dist`. The `pwa` config would then reference the path in `dist`, where the output icons would be.